# JSP is ok but Servlet = 404 resource not found (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm a java beginner and i just installed Intellij and tried the simplest project ever :
jsp :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Web Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<h1>Web calculator
</h1>
<form action="calculate" method="post">
    <p>
        Input number A <input type="number" name="a" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        Input number B <input type="number" name="b" required />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="RUN" />
</form>
<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet :

```
@WebServlet("/calculate")
public class CalculatorServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a"));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));

        int sum = (a+b);

        response.getWriter().println("sum of" +a+ "and" +b+ "is" + sum);


    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("yo Doget");
        super.doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

BUT even if i have the jsp in my browser without any problems, i can't reach the servlet, I have a 404 every time.

Somebody could help me ? Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe you have problems with your context application and the `/` can redirect you to  web service root context. Try `@WebServlet("calculate")`

Comment: @Wender I tried but still doesn't work :/